# Erlang basic list comprehenesion

Tags: erlang

I am trying to learn the basics Erlang and am having a hard time compiling the following simple list comprehension example:

```
-module(functions).
-export([add/2], [add1_comp/1]).

add(A,B) -> A+B.

add1_comp(LST) -> [X + 1 || X <- LST].
```

I am getting the following errors / warnings:

```
Bad export declaration on line 2
Function add/2 is unused line 4
Function add1_comp/1 is unused line 6
```

I have been debugging for a while now and was wondering if someone can help me identify the cause of this error?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The functions need to be exported in a list as a single argument.

```
-export([add/2, add1_comp/1]).
```

Comment: +1, Thank you. That fixed those errors however when I try to test the `add1_comp` function as follows: `add1_comp([1,2,3]).` I get the following exception: `undefined shell command add1_comp/1`, I appreciate any suggestions as to why this happening?

Comment: Are you using the module name to call the function? `functions:add1_comp([1,2,3]).`

Comment: Errrr, Thank you! I am trying to transform from Haskell, its tough ;)